# Deserialize JSON string having multiple datetime formats to c# object

Tags: c#, json, .net, json-deserialization

This is what the JSON response is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "someTicketNumber": "123456",
      "callInDateTimeUtc": "2020-09-09T20:16:26Z",
      "lastUpdatedDateTimeUtc": "2020-09-09T20:28:11Z",
      "availableDateLocalToSomeplace": "2020-09-10",
      "availableTimeLocalToSomeplace": "T10:30:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual Result of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`:

| availableDateLocalToSomeplace | availableTimeLocalToSomeplace |
| --- | --- |
| 9/10/2020 12:00:00 AM | 9/11/2020 10:30:00 AM |

My expected result:

| availableDateLocalToSomeplace | availableTimeLocalToSomeplace |
| --- | --- |
| 9/10/2020 | 10:30:00 AM |

I can't put a generic converter settings like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new 
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd" OR "THH:mm:ssZ"
});
```

because I need 2 different date time format types. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can do like this:
Create a `CustomDateTimeConverter` class, and pass the format to it's constructor, like so

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

In the c# class,

```
public partial class Tickets
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public TicketProps[] Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class TicketProps
{
    [JsonProperty("someTicketNumber")]
    public string SomeTicketNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("callInDateTimeUtc")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")]
    public DateTime? CallInDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastUpdatedDateTimeUtc")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")]
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("availableDateLocalToSomeplace")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public DateTime?AvailableDateLocalToSomeplace { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("availableTimeLocalToSomeplace")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "THH:mm:ssZ")]
    public DateTime? AvailableTimeLocalToSomeplace { get; set; }
}
```

Now your simple `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)` will work just fine.